# note move from right to down

Tags: xetex, ubuntu, tufte

There is a project [ubuntu-manual](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-manual/ubuntu-manual/trusty/files). 
Result of PDF [here](https://yadi.sk/d/NPJZUJPZSLVfc).

But note are of right.

 How is this note move from right to down?

[image: For Example]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The captions of screenshots are intended to be positioned in the margin. If the caption is running off the bottom of the page, we can fix that a bit later in the process by adding a vertical offset to move the caption up the page.

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is not bias, but what better to do a book in the A5 format. A5 compared with A4 has more advantages, for example, it's more compact, it is better to read when printed. Plus right there are a lot of empty space, and I spend a lot of paper to print A4 compared with A5. That's why I want to move right down.

Comment: When you're using the `ubuntu-manual` document class, there's no built-in way to move it. You can could the screenshot itself into the main text block, but the caption will still be typeset in the margin. You could edit the `ubuntu-manual.cls` file and change `a4paper` to `a5paper` and it will adjust the margins to better fit A5 paper. Otherwise, your best option is to use a different document class.